# How to access HTML of webpage after button press

Tags: javascript, python, html, web-scraping, python-requests

I am trying to scrape some data from the following web page:

[College Board - Georgia Institute of Technology](https://bigfuture.collegeboard.org/college-university-search/georgia-institute-of-technology?searchType=bf_site&q=&bf_cat=bf_)

But the information I need to access is only displayed after pressing the "Applying" tab on the left. Since the URL does not change, how can I simulate pressing the button in order to scrape the HTML?

I am using Python3.3 and the requests module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the page source, the information you need is hidden inside a javascript code and is calculated and rendered after the click on "Applying" link.

`requests` simply cannot make in-browser user actions and, since there is no additional requests going after clicking "Applying", you cannot get the data without actually having a real browser to run that js code. [Mechanize](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/) also wouldn't help because it cannot handle js.

Consider using [selenium](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/) (FYI, you can also [use a headless PhantomJS browser](http://www.realpython.com/blog/python/headless-selenium-testing-with-python-and-phantomjs/#.UyUsleddXQg)).

Hope that helps.